# Finding duplicate iPhone apps

Tags: iphone

How do I most efficiently determine whether my idea for an iPhone app has been done already? iTunes's search isn't great for this purpose, and the websites I've seen covering iPhone apps are not comprehensive in their coverage. (Perhaps I just haven't found THE website that does it.) I'm not yet signed up in the iPhone developer program; perhaps this search tool is in that walled garden.

Comment: It's not necessarily a dealbreaker if someone's already done it - there's almost always room for a better app (with the exception, perhaps, of the flashlight apps...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the App Store to be the best, despite its drawbacks, because of its authority and comprehensiveness. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

The following blog post

[One Juicer: Managing the App Store Beast](http://theappleblog.com/2008/12/26/one-juicer-managing-the-app-store-beast/)

has some hints how you could achieve this. For example by using AppShopper's RSS feed. Maybe you're able to scrape some data off there.

Comment: I agree that the RSS feed provided by AppShopper (appshopper.com) is a good solution for this, and their website's search feature also works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Use google search ;-) almost every app has a dedicated webpage besides on the app store and  it's not a secret that google beats the crappy app store search any day

Although google isn't the 100% solution for this, it's anyday better than most other sources